# body content out of screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click the [menu button] to show the [aside menu bar] my body content goes off of the screen.  Can you help me?

This is my code.

In [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4v63kog3/).

Html file:

```
<div class="contenido">
        <h1 class="menu-bar">Icono</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque ex iste, quod laboriosam, maiores alias, ducimus voluptate fuga soluta provident quae. Iure tempora, nemo doloribus, harum odit sequi nobis officia!</p>
      </div>
```

Js file:

```
$('.menu-bar').on('click', function() {
    $('.contenido').toggleClass('abrir');
});
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle **demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4v63kog3/1/)

Your content is positioned absolute at **100% width.**
Transform `translateX(250px)` will only move it 250px, but will **not** alter it's width.
**Instead:**

```
.abrir{
    /*transform: translateX(250px); No. */
    width: calc(100% - 250px); /* ADD THIS */
}
```

and

```
.contenido{
  right: 0; /* And this! */
}
```

PS: Frankly... see the text wrap due to some animations si quite ugly... I cannot decide what I like the most, but `translateX` (as it was), even if made text portions unreadable, wins in my eyes.